# How to provide the dynamic date value in interval range between clause in analytic function

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle19c

we provide the following

> range between interval '1' day preceding and current row.

Can we provide any date range instead of '1' day?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but with an interval literal the `'1'` part can't be a variable; but you can multiply that by some variable:

```
range between some_number * interval '1' day preceding and current row
```

You can also use [the `numtodsinterval()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NUMTODSINTERVAL.html):

```
range between numtodsinterval(some_number, 'DAY') preceding and current row
```

or if you aren't dealing with just a single unit (i.e. a number of days) you can use [the `to_dsinterval()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DSINTERVAL.html):

```
range between to_dsinterval(some_string) preceding and current row
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LOTf0SaX)

The first options can use any unit, of course; you can have multiple of 12 hours, or 3 seconds, or whatever you want.

The last option allows two formats, so you can pass in an ISO-format duration like `'P5D'` or `'P1D12H'` or 'P6D12H13M14.567S' etc., or an 'SQL format' as `6 12:13:14.567'.